# Recyclerview solamente muestra un número limitado de elementos

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

me encuentro en un problema al mostrar elementos por medio de un Recyclerview, cuando agrego 5 elementos a la lista para mostrar, solamente me muestra 2 elementos y los restantes no lo muestran. He estado con ese problema durante varios días sin poder resolverlo, espero que Puede ayudar a ver el error o mejor sugerencia para poder resolverlo.

A continuación muestro una imagen de como se deben de mostrar los elementos.
[image: Vista del Recyclerview]

En el siguiente código se muestra el adaptador en donde se obtienen los elementos para poder mostrar los elementos.

```
public class AddXboxGamesViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddXboxGamesViewAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

private Context context;

private List<Qapla> qaplaGamesList;

private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

public AddXboxGamesViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    qaplaGamesList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setQaplaList(List<Qapla> qaplaList){
    this.qaplaGamesList = qaplaList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.matches_games_card, parent, false);
    GameViewHolder viewHolder = new GameViewHolder(view);

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mUsersDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GameViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    final Qapla qapla = qaplaGamesList.get(position);
    final String game = qapla.getUserName();

    holder.tvUserName.setText(qapla.getUserName());//NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO


    if (game.equals("xFifa")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Fifa 18");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fifa19_xbox_wizard);
        holder.rvPlatformColor.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_xbox));
    }else if (game.equals("xGears")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Gears of War 4");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.gow_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gow_xbox_wizard);
        holder.rvPlatformColor.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_xbox));
    }else if (game.equals("xHalo")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Halo");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.halo_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.halo_xbox_wizard);
        holder.rvPlatformColor.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_xbox));
    }else if (game.equals("xOver")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Overwatch");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.overwatch_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.overwatch_xbox_wizard);
        holder.rvPlatformColor.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_xbox));
    }else if (game.equals("psFifa")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Fifa 18");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa19ps);
    }else if (game.equals("psOver")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Overwatch");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.overwatch_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.overwatchps);
    }else if (game.equals("pFifa")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Fifa 18");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa_logo);
    }else if (game.equals("pGears")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Gears of War 4");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.gow_logo);
    }else if (game.equals("pHalo")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Halo");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.halo_logo);
    }else if (game.equals("pHearth")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Hearthstone");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.hearthstone_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.hearthstone_wizard);
    }else if (game.equals("pOver")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Overwatch");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.overwatch_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.overwatch_pc_wizard);
    }else if (game.equals("pcLol")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("LoL");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.lol_logo);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.league_of_legends_wizard);
    }else if (game.equals("aClash")){
        holder.tvUserName.setText("Clash Royale");//NOMBRE DEL juego y plataforma
        holder.imgLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.clash_royale);
        holder.imgGame.setImageResource(R.drawable.clashroyale);
    }

    holder.rvCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String myUserUid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            obtainPlatformGame(game, myUserUid);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return qaplaGamesList.size();
}

public class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView tvUserName;

    ImageView imgLogo;
    RelativeLayout rvCard;
    ImageView imgGame;
    RelativeLayout rvPlatformColor;

    public GameViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserNameSearch);
        imgLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgUserSearch);
        rvCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvCard);
        imgGame = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgGame);
        rvPlatformColor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvPlatformColor);
    }
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    qaplaGamesList.remove(position);
    // notify the item removed by position
    // to perform recycler view delete animations
    // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreItem(Qapla item, int position) {
    qaplaGamesList.add(position, item);
    // notify item added by position
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void obtainPlatformGame(String gameToAdd, String userUid){

    String gameToAddPlatform = "";

    if (gameToAdd.equals("xGears")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "xboxLive";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("xFifa")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "xboxLive";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("xHalo")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "xboxLive";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("xOver")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "xboxLive";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("psFifa")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "psn";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("psOver")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "psn";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("pOver")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "battlenet";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("pHearth")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "battlenet";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("pcLol")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "lolTag";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("pGears")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "xboxLive";

    }if (gameToAdd.equals("aClash")){

        gameToAddPlatform = "clashTag";
    }

    obtainUserName(userUid,gameToAdd,gameToAddPlatform);

}


public void obtainUserName(final String userUid, final String gameToAdd, final String gameToAddPlatform){

    Log.d("gameToaddPlatform",gameToAddPlatform);

    mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userUid).child("userName").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String userName = dataSnapshot.toString();
                addGame(userUid,userName,gameToAdd, gameToAddPlatform);
                Log.d("userNameObtained",userName);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
public void addGame(final String userUid, final String userName, final String gameToAdd, final String gameToAddPlatform){

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String userId = user.getUid();
    Log.d("obtainThemadre",userId);

    mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userId).child("games").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

            }else {
                Log.d("laNulidad","devuelve que no existen los atributos");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userId).child("games").child(gameToAdd).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

            }else {
                Log.d("informationGames","esta cargando la informacion");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userId).child("games").child(gameToAdd).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                /**El usuario ya tiene el juego en sus juegos*/
                // gameAlert();
            }else {

                Log.d("llegamosAagregar","si esta llegando a esta parte" + gameToAddPlatform);
                /**Creamos los atributos del juego*/
                int gamelvl = 0;
                int gameExp = 0;
                int gameWins = 0;
                int gameLoses = 0;

                final Games games = new Games(gameToAdd,gamelvl,gameExp,gameWins,gameLoses,userName,userUid);


                Log.d("agregarJuego", userUid);

                /**Revisamos si el usuario ya tiene juegos de la misma plataforma,*/
                mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userId).child("gamerTags").child(gameToAddPlatform).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            //Do nothing

                            /**Si ya tiene los gamertags del juego, le preguntamos si esta seguro de agregar el juego*/
                            // gameAlerta(games);

                        }else {

                            /**No tiene el juego y tampoco los gamertag del juego
                             * lo pasamos al siguiente activity para pedirle los gamertag del juego*/
                            Log.d("verify", "gameToAdd: "+gameToAdd+ " ,games: "+games+" ,gamePlatform: "+gameToAddPlatform);

                            if (gameToAddPlatform.equals("xboxLive")){
                                Log.d("verify", "in gamePlatform: "+gameToAddPlatform);
                                       /*Intent i = new Intent(AddGamesActivity.this, VerifyXboxTag.class);
                                       i.putExtra("games",games);
                                       i.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                       i.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                       Log.d("verify", "gameToAdd: "+gameToAdd+ " ,games: "+games+" ,gamePlatform: "+gameToAddPlatform);
                                       startActivity(i);
                                       finish();*/
                                /**Metodo comentado que sirve para usar el api de XboxLive*/
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGamerTagsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("games",games);
                                intent.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                intent.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                ((SelectGameToAddActivity)context).finish();
                            }else if (gameToAddPlatform.equals("battlenet")){
                                Log.d("verify", "in gamePlatform: "+gameToAddPlatform);
                                //a valida callback url https://dev.battle.net/

                                // final Intent intent = new Intent(AddGamesActivity.this, Add_battlenetTag.class);
                                // Send BnOAuth2Params
                                // Send redirect Activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGamerTagsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("games",games);
                                intent.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                intent.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                ((SelectGameToAddActivity)context).finish();

                                /**Metodo comentado que sirve para usar el api de Battlenet*/
                                       /*Intent i = new Intent(AddGamesActivity.this, VerifyBattleNetTag.class);
                                       i.putExtra("games",games);
                                       i.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                       i.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                       Log.d("verify", "gameToAdd: "+gameToAdd+ " ,games: "+games+" ,gamePlatform: "+gameToAddPlatform);
                                       startActivity(i);*/
                            }else{
                                Log.d("verify", "no platform selected");
                                if (gameToAdd.equals("aClash")){
                                    Log.d("verify", "in gameToAdd: "+gameToAdd);
                                    Intent i = new Intent(context, VerifyCRTag.class);
                                    i.putExtra("games",games);
                                    i.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                    i.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                    context.startActivity(i);
                                    ((SelectGameToAddActivity)context).finish();
                                } else if (gameToAdd.equals("pcLol")){
                                    Log.d("verify", "in gameToAdd: "+gameToAdd);
                                    /**Metodo comentado que sirve para usar el api de LOL*/
                                           /*Intent i = new Intent(AddGamesActivity.this, VerifyLoLTag.class);
                                           i.putExtra("games",games);
                                           i.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                           i.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                           startActivity(i);
                                           finish();*/

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGamerTagsActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("games",games);
                                    intent.putExtra("gameToAdd",gameToAdd);
                                    intent.putExtra("gamePlatform",gameToAddPlatform);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                    ((SelectGameToAddActivity)context).finish();
                                }else {
                                    Log.d("verify", "in else: "+gameToAdd);
                                    Intent i = new Intent(context, AddGamerTagsActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra("games", games);
                                    i.putExtra("gameToAdd", gameToAdd);
                                    i.putExtra("gamePlatform", gameToAddPlatform);
                                    context.startActivity(i);
                                    ((SelectGameToAddActivity)context).finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Agrego el código de la clase en donde se muestra la vista del Recyclerview, se maneja más de un Recyclerview a la ves porqué se están trabajando con más de una vista a la vez dentro de la misma antividad.

```
public class SelectGameToAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


/**RecyclerView de plataformas de juegos y equipos*/
RecyclerView recyclerViewXboxGames, recyclerViewPs4Games, recyclerViewPcGames;

/**LISTA PARA AGREGAR JUEGOS DE XBOX**/
List<Qapla> qaplaXboxGamesList;

/**Lista para agregar juegos de ps4*/
List<Qapla> qaplaPs4GamesList;

/**Lista para agregar juegos de pc*/
List<Qapla> qaplaPcGamesList;

/**ADAPTER PARA JUEGOS DE XBOX**/
private AddXboxGamesViewAdapter adapterXboxGames;

/**ADAPTER PARA JUEGOS DE PS4*/
private AddPs4GamesViewAdapter adapterPs4Games;

/**AFAPTER PARA JUEGOS DE PC*/
private AddPcGamesViewAdapter adapterPcGames;

/**LinearLayout que contienen los recyclerview de las plataformas
 * de los diferentes juegos xbox,ps4 y pc*/

LinearLayout linearPs4Games, linearPcGames;


ImageView close;




FrameLayout frXboxgames, frPcGames, frPs4Games;



/**FIREBASE DATA**/
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mGamesDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabaseReference;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_game_to_add);

    /**FIREBASE DATA**/
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mGamesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Gamers");
    mUsersDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");



    /**LinearLayout que contienen los recyclerview de las diferentes plataformas de juegos*/
    //linearXboxGames = view.findViewById(R.id.linearXboxGames);
    linearPs4Games = findViewById(R.id.linearPs4Games);
    linearPcGames = findViewById(R.id.linearPcGames);


    frXboxgames = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout_xbox);
    frPs4Games = findViewById(R.id.framelayout_ps4);
    frPcGames = findViewById(R.id.framelayout_movile_pc);

    close = findViewById(R.id.img_clear);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });



    /**RecyclerView de juegos*/
    recyclerViewXboxGames = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerViewPs4Games = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPs4Games);
    recyclerViewPcGames = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPcGames);


    /**Inicializamos los adaptadores para los recyclerview horizontales de juegos de Xbox*/
    recyclerViewXboxGames.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerViewXboxGames.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewXboxGames.setHasFixedSize(true);
    qaplaXboxGamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterXboxGames = new AddXboxGamesViewAdapter(this);
    recyclerViewXboxGames.setAdapter(adapterXboxGames);


    /**Inicializamos los adaptadores para los recyclerview horizontales de juegos de ps4*/
    recyclerViewPs4Games.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerPs4 = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerViewPs4Games.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerPs4);
    recyclerViewPs4Games.setHasFixedSize(true);
    qaplaPs4GamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterPs4Games = new AddPs4GamesViewAdapter(this);
    recyclerViewPs4Games.setAdapter(adapterPs4Games);


    /**Inicializamos los adaptadores para los recyclerview horizontales de juegos de pc*/
    recyclerViewPcGames.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerPc = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerViewPcGames.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerPc);
    recyclerViewPcGames.setHasFixedSize(true);
    qaplaPcGamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterPcGames = new AddPcGamesViewAdapter(this);
    recyclerViewPcGames.setAdapter(adapterPcGames);


    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    if (user != null) {

        String userUid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        loadMyGames2(userUid);


        mUsersDatabaseReference.child(userUid).child("games").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                }else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}

String[] allGames = {"xFifa","xGears","xHalo","xOver","psFifa","psOver","pGears","pHalo","pHearth","pOver","pcLol","aClash"};

public void loadMyGames2(String myUid){
    for (int j = 0;j < allGames.length; j++) {
        final String gameCode = allGames[j];


        if (gameCode.equals("xFifa")||gameCode.equals("xGears")||gameCode.equals("xHalo")||gameCode.equals("xOver")){
            loadMyXboxGamesData(gameCode);
        }
        if (gameCode.equals("psFifa")||gameCode.equals("psOver")){
            loadMyPs4GamesData(gameCode);
        }
        if(gameCode.equals("aClash")||gameCode.equals("pGears")||gameCode.equals("pHearth")||gameCode.equals("pOver")||gameCode.equals("pcLol")){
            loadMyPcGamesData(gameCode);
        }
    }
}


public void loadMyXboxGamesData(final String gameCode){

    Log.d("JuegosParaAgregar",gameCode);

    qaplaXboxGamesList.add(new Qapla(gameCode,"","","","","",""));
    adapterXboxGames.setQaplaList(qaplaXboxGamesList);
    adapterXboxGames.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

public void loadMyPs4GamesData(final String gameCode){

    Log.d("JuegosParaAgregarPS4",gameCode);

    linearPs4Games.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    qaplaPs4GamesList.add(new Qapla(gameCode,"","","","","",""));
    adapterPs4Games.setQaplaList(qaplaPs4GamesList);
    adapterPs4Games.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

public void loadMyPcGamesData(final String gameCode){

    Log.d("JuegosParaAgregarPc",gameCode);
    linearPcGames.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    qaplaPcGamesList.add(new Qapla(gameCode,"","","","","",""));
    adapterPcGames.setQaplaList(qaplaPcGamesList);
    adapterPcGames.notifyDataSetChanged();

}}
```

Comment: Hola, en principio no le veo ningun problema al codigo. Debugea el metodo getItemCount() del adapter y asegurate que la lista tenga 5 elementos y no 2. Tambien te recomiendo que simplifiques la prueba harcodeando los item del array que le vas a setear al adapter ya que simplemente leyendo el metodo donde lo cargas es imposible saber de antemano cuantos elementos tendra el array